# Variable not accessible in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have a file called `file_with_data_from_server.php`, this receives `$_POST['data]` from an `AJAX` call. I managed to make a new array to contain the data from the server. This `file_with_data_from_server.php` is then included in another `.php` file. Naturally, all the variables present on the `file_with_data_from_server.php` can be accessed on the file where it was included, but in my case, I cannot access a variable wherein it's value is taken from the `json_decoded` data. This is the code on `file_with_data_from_server.php`,

```
        $data_for_reports = $_POST['data']; // data from server

        $rrow = json_decode($data_for_reports);
        $dates_for_reports = array();
        foreach($rrow as $rr){
            $dates_for_reports[] = $rr->time_period;
        }
        $current_date_with_data = end($dates_for_reports);      // this contains data like '201301'
```

in my `.php` file where I included `file_with_data_from_server.php`, I have this code,

```
        include('file_with_data_from_server.php');
        echo '<pre>';
            print_r('test'.$current_date_with_data);
        echo '</pre>';
```

I'm trying to print the value of `$current_date_with_data` variable but it displays nothing.

Comment: Did you try to dump that variable (in the first file)?

Comment: @Uby, of course and it has data on it.

Comment: So you're posting to `file_with_data_from_server.php` but including it within another .php page?

Comment: @juco, Yes, that's right. What do you think is the problem here?

Comment: are you able to access any other data from `file_with_data_from_server.php` in your second file? I would just double check that the files are being properly included

Comment: @br14np, Yes, I tried making a sample variable on the first file which contains `asd123` and echoed it on the second file and it succesfully printed it. But if I assign that sample variable with any data on the first file, it was not being printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather you are including `file_with_data_from_server.php` in another PHP script (hereafter referred to as `other.php`) and posting to `file_with_data_from_server.php`, expecting the variables to be printed in `other.php`. This is not going to work, as at no point is `other.php` actually called.

Consider this:

**a.php**

```
$myVar = $_POST;
```

**b.php**

```
include('a.php');
var_dump($myVar);
```

If you POST to `a.php` - `b.php` is never invoked! It's `include` and `var_dump` in this case will never be executed as only `a.php` has been invoked.

However, with the above, if you were to post to `b.php` (which is including `a.php`) this would work as you appear to expect.

Comment: So you're suggesting I post to `b.php` instead of posting it to `a.php` ?

Comment: In that scenario `a.php` has no idea that `b.php` wants to include it - it's never loaded. So in this situation you would have to, yes.

Comment: It seems like the poster can't be making this mistake since they say that `"test"` is getting output. But they might be talking about 2 different requests.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `print_r()` call output `"test"`? It could be that `$current_date_with_data` contains a `null` or something that does not stringify to anything.

This is a simple way to check every variable you're defined:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo HtmlSpecialChars(print_r($GLOBALS, true));
echo "</pre>";
```

**UPDATE**

It sounds like juco found your solution. You are not actually posted the data to your second php file. The data will only be available to `file_with_data_from_server.php` in the initial post, not subsequent requests.

If you need to send data in one request and access it later in another request, you need to store the data somewhere, such a session variable or in a database.

Every request in PHP is new and carries no data from previous requests. This is called being "stateless". Google has a lot of results explaining statelessness in web apps.

http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/sessions-and-cookies-adding-state-to-a-stateless-protocol

Comment: It certainly outputs `"test"`, just that alone.

Comment: What happens when you dump all globals using my example code?

Comment: It returns this error, `Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency`.

Comment: Oops. Try replacing `var_export` with `print_r`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It outputs a nested array. I am assuming you want me to find the variable `$current_date_with_data` but it was not there.